# repeater format

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am quite blur in using repeater

is that any way do not display data in first row of sql?

**data inside my db**

```
userName  Phone
Admin     admin
roy       012345678
ken       012345678
```

**output from my code**

userName:  Admin

Phone:  admin

```
------------------------------------
```

userName: roy

Phone: 012345678

```
------------------------------------
```

userName: ken

Phone: 012345678

```
------------------------------------
```

**Expected output**

```
userName: roy
phone: 012345678
------------------------------------
userName: ken
phone: 012345678
----------------------
```

below here is my code

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" >

        <ItemTemplate>

    Course Name: <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "subject" )%>

    <br />

    Subject Info: <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"subjectIntroduction")%>

    <hr />
```

```
</asp:Repeater>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [subject], [subjectIntroduction] FROM [courseSubjectTable]">    

</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" >

     <ItemTemplate>
userName:&nbsp;
    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "subject" ) +"<br/>"%>
phone:&nbsp;
    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"subjectIntroduction")  + "<hr/>"%>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [subject], [subjectIntroduction] FROM [courseSubjectTable]">    

</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**Use this not to show admin:**

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [subject], [subjectIntroduction] FROM [courseSubjectTable] where userName <> 'Admin'">
```

Comment: ya, i done this, my problem now i do not wish to display admin for enduser

Comment: Then change your SQL query to exclude the records you don't want. Or don't store that data in the same table as the other date.

Comment: Check above updated answer of your query. Please accept it and upvote answer if u get the solution.